# Json Serialize data with different property name

Tags: java, json

I have an input Json as show below:-

```
{
    "stress": {
      "FxPOS": {
        "SX": [
          -14.2581,
          -15.6962,
          -12.6547,
          -13.639,
          -6.305,
          7.0567,
          15.508
        ]
      }
    }
}
```

I am trying to map this to a java class as shown below:-

```
public class DTO implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;
        private Stress stress;

        @Getter
        @Setter
        @JsonAutoDetect(getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
        public static class Stress implements Serializable {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 5133888753296054639L;
            @JsonSerialize
            @JsonProperty("FxPOS")
            private Config fxPOS;
            }
            }



   @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @JsonSerialize
    @JsonAutoDetect(getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
    public class Config implements Serializable {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -7335939612336666586L;
        @JsonSerialize
        @JsonProperty("SX")
        private String sx;
        }
```

After Mapping the data and re-serializing it to JSON am getting the below output:

```
{
        "stress": {
          "fxPOS": {
            "sx": [
              -14.2581,
              -15.6962,
              -12.6547,
              -13.639,
              -6.3305,
              7.0567,
              15.508
            ]
          }
        }
    }
```

Can anyone please tell me where am i doing wrong?
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How do you persist your data? With jpa annotations you can give @Column annotation to your properties to specify column name.

Comment: The data is persisted as a string into a single column.

Comment: You may need to implement your own naming strategy using [PropertyNamingStrategy](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.html)

Comment: Can you share your persistence logic code blocks?

Comment: @NullPointerException -Is there a way to do it without using the NamingStrategy i do not want to apply this strategy on all the property of my class.

Comment: as far as I know  No

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve this by defining explicit getter and setter methods and annotating these with `@JsonGetter` and `@JsonSetter`.
In these annotations you can specify the names from which name to deserialize and in which name to serialize. Else the name will just be derived from the property names.

E.g:

```
public class DTO implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;
    private Stress stress;

    public static class Stress implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 5133888753296054639L;

        private Config fxPOS;

        @JsonGetter("FxPOS")
        public Config getFxPOS() {
            return fxPOS;
        }

        @JsonSetter("FxPOS")
        public void setFxPOS(int fxPOS) {
            this.fxPOS = fxPOS;
        }
    }
}

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonSerialize
public class Config implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7335939612336666586L;

    private String sx;

    @JsonGetter("SX")
    public String getSx() {
        return sx;
    }

    @JsonSetter("SX")
    public void setRed(int sx) {
        this.sx = sx;
    }
}
```